# Extract feeds from web page

Tags: javascript, python, rss, feed, text-extraction

I'm looking for a code snippet (language is not important here) that will
extract all feeds (RSS, atom etc.) that is associated with this page.

So input is `URL` and output `list of channels`.

Important is completeness, it means if the page has associated some information channel
it should be found.

I'm asking preferably for what to find in HTML code and where to find to cover completeness.

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You find feeds in the `head` tag in html files. There they should be specified as `link` tags with an associated content type and a href attribute specifying it's location.

To extract all feed urls from a page using python you could use something like this:

```
import urllib
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class FeedParser(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.feeds = set()
        HTMLParser.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs): 
        if tag == 'link':
            try:
                href = [attr[1] for attr in attrs if attr[0] == 'href'][0]
            except IndexError:
                return None         
            else:
                if ('type', 'application/atom+xml') in attrs or ('type', 'application/rss+xml') in attrs:
                    self.feeds.add(href)    


def get_all_feeds_from_url(url):
    f = urllib.urlopen(url)
    contents = f.read()
    f.close()

    parser = FeedParser()
    parser.feed(contents)
    parser.close()

    return list(parser.feeds)
```

This code would have to be extended quite a bit though if you want to cover all the quirky ways a feed can be added to a html page.

Comment: Thank you for snippet, but many pages don't use the standard place and probably use the quirky ways. Look e.g. at [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/us/index.html) web page. Can you find out what "quirky ways" are often used?

Comment: Sorry, but they have a very non-standard way of listing RSS feeds. The only way to find them programmatically is to crawl their whole web page (i.e. go through all their hyperlinks and check: if RSS feed: add to collection, if html: check all hyperlinks and repeat)

Comment: Can I check somehow that a link is actually a channel? (atom or RSS or something else)